# Learning JavaScript with sound design techniques?

Tags: tutorial

Another poster started some wonderful tutorials (http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/17435/interactive-audio-learn-how-to-build-web-mobile-audio-applications-using-javas) along the lines of what I'm looking for. But I'm pretty impatient for the next tutorial and would love to dive into this more ASAP. Know of any pointers?

Comment: Define pointers. If you just want to create more, then learn briefly the basics of the Javascript language (plenty of sources, perhaps http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript is one of the "less dry", but still general ones) and then read the documentation of the javascript libraries (mainly the WebAudio API, https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) that the tutorial uses. If what you've learned this far has been totally new, then it might be easiest to understand first what you've written and just build on that.

Comment: I've just noticed I learn better when it's within a digital audio context is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorial 4 & 5 have been up for awhile.

http://interactiveaudio.wikiaudio.org/how-to/javascript-variables-primitive-data-types-part-1/

http://interactiveaudio.wikiaudio.org/how-to/javascript-variables-primitive-data-types-part-2/

Comment: Sick! Wonder why I never got the e-mail...

Answer (score 0):

Well I just started the same course and would love to get to part 5 :)
So no answer, but a recommendation/bump!

Nice tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

Codecademy is not bad, but some of the lessons have problems with the online interpreter not working real well. Well, I had problems with the Python course anyway. Just a heads up.